# Find closest lat long to an input lat long (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: geometry, sql-server, nearest-neighbor

I have a point cloud in my database (SQL Server 2008 spatial). That is about 6 million records. There are 3 columns: id, value, geom. What is the optimal way of getting the 'value' at input lat long??

I am new to spatial queries in SQL Server 2008. Can someone post a simple example of finding the point in geom column, matching or closest from the input lat long?

Comment: Have you [created a spatial index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934196.aspx)?

Comment: I tried. But there are 6 million records and creating index fails with different reasons. I am trying now to create a blank table, add a spatial index on geom and then add data. does that work?

Comment: What errors are you getting?  An index can slow loading down a lot, for that many rows I think adding an index after loading would be a lot faster.  Performance will depend greatly on the index, so it is worth getting that right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is Nearest Neighbor Query. Look at the following links, I think you will find what you are looking for.

- [Nearest Neighbor Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)
- [Nearest Neighbors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/isaac/nearest-neighbors)
- [The nearest neighbor optimization in SQL Server Denali](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/the-nearest-neighbor-optimization-in-sql-server-denali/)

Answer (score 4):

This uses [Geography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx) not [Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895270.aspx) (if data is Lat/Lng you data should be Geography Type not Geometry)

***"The SQL Server geography data type stores ellipsoidal (round-earth) data, such as GPS latitude and longitude coordinates."***

To Select the Top 5 Nearest Records from a lat/lng (-122.0 37.0) point you can use.

```
SELECT   TOP 5
         geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.0 37.0)', 4326).STDistance(p) 
FROM     markers
WHERE    geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.0 37.0)', 4326).STDistance(p) < 25
ORDER BY geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.0 37.0)', 4326).STDistance(p);
```

Comment: What is p? sorry i am a new bie thats why asking

Comment: DECLARE @p geography